# If a photon is powerful enough, will it not pass through glass?

Tags: visible-light, photons, glass

So I know how glass works, it has a large electron gap so the photons that hit it don't have enough energy to move the electrons into a high energy state and instead pass through because the amount of energy can't be in-between. But, does this also mean that if you had a powerful enough photon, would that be able to be absorbed and therefore not pass through?

Comment: What do you mean by "powerful enough photon"? If you just mean "a photon with a high enough energy", then that wording is *much* more standard and understandable.

Comment: As per Emilio Pisanty's comment, if the question was about photon with really high frequency (or energy $E = h f$), then there is a good chance of photon being absorbed and the glass undergoing fluorescence.

Answer (score 3):

[image: xray]

> [X-ray attenuation and emission spectra.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/X-ray-attenuation-and-emission-spectra-X-ray-mass-attenuation-coefficients-of-adipose_fig3_265646533) X-ray mass attenuation coefficients of adipose tissue, water, Pyrex glass, bone, and elemental iodine show how iodine has a 5- to 30-fold stronger attenuation than biological materials and glass in the range of photon energies produced by a tungsten target (W emission). Figure generated de novo from data published in Hammersberg et al., Linköping Electron Artic Mech Eng, 1998, 1, 1–13, and Hubbell and Seltzer, 1996.

[Attenuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation) gives the number of photons surviving going through a medium.

> But, does this also mean that if you had a powerful enough photon, would that be able to be absorbed and therefore not pass through?

As you see there is a probability of being absorbed and also a probabilty of going through glass without scattering or being absorbed. x ray energies are high energy photons. So it will depend on the "luck" of a particular single photon, whether it will be absorbed or not.

Comment: This only tangentially addresses the question.

Comment: @Acccumulation  I have edited

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you mean

> does this also mean that if you had [a photon with a large-enough photon energy], would that be able to be absorbed and therefore not pass through?

then yes, that is correct. The transmittance of glass plummets in the ultraviolet, once the wavelength becomes short enough that the photon energy becomes larger than the bandgap of the material.

Below is one example from Kopp Glass - notice that the absorbance (blue) shoots up at the low-wavelength end of the plot (to the left), while the transmittivity (red) plummets to zero in that regime and never recovers. (This particular spectrum also has several absorbance bands in the middle of the visible, which probably give it a specific colour, and which come from impurities in the material.)

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Image source](http://www.koppglass.com/blog/optical-properties-of-glass-how-light-and-glass-interact/)</sup>